# converting characters in a character array into integers

Tags: c

My Question: How do I get an integer variable to recognize the value of a character stored within a character array?

My Problem: I am unable to get the integer variable number to store the correct value that is represented by the element within the character array array1[].

Some Background:
I have written a function called Celcius_to_fahrenheit, which does a simple conversion. It takes a character array, containing 3 numbers stored as characters, and assigns each element within the array to an integer variable named number. The variable number, after potentially being multiplied against something, is then added to the float variable Celsius. Once Celsius is obtained, a simple conversion is done to produce fahrenheit and fahrenheit is returned.

```
// Converts Celcius to Fahrenheit for Tmax and Tmin`

float Celsius_to_fahrenheit(char array1[])

{

    float fahrenheit, Celsius;
    int i, number;
    Celsius = fahrenheit = number = 0;

    for(i = 0; i < strlen(array1); i++)
    {
        if (i == 0)
        {
            number = (int)array1[i];
            Celsius += (float)number * 10;
        }
        if (i == 1)
        {
            number = (int)array1[i];
            Celsius += number;
        }
        if (i == 2)
        {
            number = (int)array1[i];
            Celsius += (float)number * 0.10;
        }
    }
    printf("%.1f\n", Celsius);
    fahrenheit = Celsius * (9.0/5.0) + 32.0;

    return fahrenheit;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The `char` representation of decimal digits is not the same as the number itself.  For example, `'4'` does not equal `4`, but rather `52`.  You can correct this by subtracting `'0'` from the array element to get the actual value, e.g. `number = (int)(array1[i] - '0')`.

Comment: Makes sense, because '4' is stored as the decimal 52 and '0' is stored as the decimal 48. Therefore,  subtracting '4' - '0' should produce a decimal number of 4. Thanks for the assistance!

Comment: @Liftalots Exactly - ASCII characters are set up such that the representation of the numbers 0 through 9 are adjacent and in ascending order.  They're also conveniently aligned such that the lowest 4 bits represent the number itself as well, so you can also write `number = (int)(array1[i] & 0x0F)`.

Answer (score 1):

A `char` value is simply a signed number in the range of `(-128 < c < 127)`. There is no conversion necessary to have an integer recognize the value of a character stored in the character array.

```
int i = array[n];
```

Will provide `i` with the value of the character stored at the `nth` element of `array`. You can see the value conversion at [**Ascii Table.com**](http://www.asciitable.com/). Note: to prove to yourself there is no conversion necessary or required, look at the value as both a character and an integer:

```
int a = 48;
printf ("the integer value: %d,  the character: %c\n", a, a);
```

The value of `a` never changes in memory, it is just a matter of what you have it represent. A very simple example is:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main () {

    char array[] = "this is my array.";
    int i = array[3];

    printf ("\n  the integer value of i: %d,  the character i represents: %c\n\n", i, i);

    return 0;
}
```

**Output**

```
$ ./bin/charint

  the integer value of i: 115,  the character i represents: s
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have a look at an ASCII table you can see the equivalent integer values for characters. E.g if you wanted to know the integer value for char '0', it will be 48. An easy implementation to convert char to int is to take the char and minus 48. (or minus '0' , since char '0' is equal to 48).

Answer (score 0):

You've already got several answers that explain how to get the number from a character. I am going to present a simpler version of the `for` loop to accumulate the number.

Use:

```
int number = 0;
int len = strlen(array1);
for(i = len-1; i >= 0; --i)
{
   number = number*10 + array1[i] - '0';
}

Celsius = number;
```